# Behaviour of static keyword in inline function

Tags: c, compiler-construction, static, inline

I have belows test program

```
#include<stdio.h>
inline int func ()
{
static int a = 10;
a++;
return a;
}

int main()
{
int x,y,z;
x=func();
printf("x is %d\n",x);
y=func();
printf("y is %d\n",y);
z=func();
printf("z is %d\n",z);

return 0;
}
```

When i run i get op as

```
x is 11
y is 12
z is 13
```

As inline function means 
programmer has requested that the compiler **insert the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called**, rather than generating code to call the function in the one place it is defined

So does not o/p should be

```
x is 11
y is 11
z is 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of the `inline` keyword is not entirely correct. Since C99 `inline` simply tells the compiler that it mustn't necessarily emit the code for the function in a compilation unit that sees it. It avoids "multiply defined symbols" errors through linking.

To your question about `static` declarations inside `inline` functions: C99 just forbids them. So your problem doesn't occur with conforming code.

You may be interested in some reading about [`inline` and C99](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/myth-and-reality-about-inline-in-c99/)

Also some nitpick, function declarations for functions that don't receive parameters should use `void` as a declaration list. Declarations with `()` refer to functions with an arbitrary number of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Putting `inline` on a function should not change the semantics of the generated code.

The [C draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) has this to say;

> An inline deﬁnition of a function with external linkage shall *not contain a deﬁnition of a
>   modiﬁable object with static or thread storage duration*, and shall not contain a reference
>   to an identiﬁer with internal linkage.

In other words, if the inline function is shared between translation units, the compiler will not allow the inlining of methods with references to static variables, and if it's local to a translation unit, the compiler knows about every instantiation of the inline and it's easy to generate one and only one instance of the static.